# Simulate continuous insert to a DB table

Tags: java, python, csv, relational-database

I have CSV datasets that I want to insert to a database, Postgres or MySQL. The dataset has a timestamp column, and I want to insert its rows based on (or as an offset of) that timestamp, so as to simulate continuous (or streaming) inserts. Do you know of any tool or library that does that? Or do I have to write some custom code? If you know of any, I prefer to do this in Java or Python.

Comment: SO is not a place to get someone to do your coding, its to get help with coding problems. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @Eli Read my question again Mr. I am asking for a library or tool. I'm fine doing the code. I just want to avoid doing it if there's a library or tool existing for the task that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). Not sure if this will solve your issue but I am sure that it will be helpful to you.